# Python, how to fix if and else statements

Tags: python-3.x

The question I am asking is: Write an expression that prints **'You must be rich!'** if the variables `young` and `famous` are both `True`.

Sample output with inputs `'True' 'True'`: `You must be rich!`

What is wrong with the code below? Output is `'There is always the lottery...'` instead of `'You must be rich!'`.

```
young = (input() == 'True')
famous = (input() == 'True')

if (young == 'True') and (famous == 'True'):
    print('You must be rich!')
else:
    print('There is always the lottery...')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking your values against the strings 'True' when really you need to check them against the boolean value True. Just drop the quotation marks.

```
if (young == True) and (famous == True): 
    print('You must be rich!') 
else: 
    print('There is always the lottery...')
```

Answer (score 2):

What your code is doing is checking if `young` is equal to the string `'True'` and if `famous` is equal to the string `'True'`. You want

```
if (young and famous):
```

or if you want to write it out

```
if (young == True and famous == True):
```

Answer (score 0):

The first and second lines are actually booleans.

After the input function evaluates you are given either `True` or `False` depending on what you typed in.

So the if statement is evaluating

`if ({True or False} == 'True') and ({True or False} == 'True'):`

This will always evaluate to false as the boolean and the string representation are never equivalent.

Change to this

```
if input('Are you young?')=='True' and input('Are you famous?')=='True':
  print('you must me rich!')
else:
  print('there is always the lottery')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment operators:

```
young = (input() == 'True')
famous = (input() == 'True')
```

result in those two variables being set as booleans. However your if statement is comparing them to strings:

```
if (young == 'True') and (famous == 'True'):
```

Drop the single quotes around True in each instance above and it'll work because then the comparison is against the boolean value True, not the string 'True'.

Note that you could have checked this using the type keyword to print what type it is. I.e.:

```
print(type(young))
print(type('True'))
```